# need to create a welcome username and a DropDownlist on the second webpage?

Tags: asp.net

This is the Login page.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(...);
            cn.Open();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM inquiry2 WHERE email = @email AND passwrd = @passwrd", cn);

            using (cn)
            {
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", this.TextBox1.Text);
                sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passwrd", this.TextBox2.Text);

                sda.Fill(dt);



                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    Response.Redirect("QUESTION3.aspx");
                }

                else
                {

                    Response.Write("INVALID Username and Password, Try Again!");
                }



            }//end using cn

            cn.Close();

        }//END BUTTON1_CLICK


    }
}
```

I want to utilize the information above in a Welcome page once the user logs in with a dropdownlist with data from the data table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's only going to be a few records, the best way to do this is using a session variable.  this can be done as follows:

```
Session.Add["dt"] = dt;
```

then can be retrieved as follows on the page you need it on:

```
dt = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
```

then you can do a simple databind as follows:

```
ddlYourDropDown.DataSource = dt;
ddlYourDropDown.DataBind();
```

I did notice one other thing looking at your code, it looks like you're passing your passwords back and forth as clear text?  I'm hoping that in the actual site you're doing some sort of encryption against the password prior to retrieving it from the database, as this is a rather nasty security flaw.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to complete it! great tip. Also, this is just a prototype for now